# Trying to make this work... (Xcode for mac NOT iPhone) - ArrayController

Tags: objective-c, macos

I'm writing a stopwatch application for mac, and am currently working on the 'laps' feature. I am putting the laps into a Table View for better organization. I'm using an Array Controller to put things into the table.

Basically, what I'm trying to do is this:

```
[arrayController addObject: [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"Lap 1",
@"lapNumber", nil]];
```

That works fine and dandy, but I'd like to be able to control that number next to lap using an integer representing the number of laps, called numLaps. Thus, my code would be:

```
[arrayController addObject: [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"Lap %i", 
numLaps, @"lapNumber", nil]];
```

However, as that is more than two commas before the nil, I think the program is getting screwed up. I am getting the following thrown in the console, though I don't exactly understand what it means / how to fix it:

```
2013-09-03 16:52:31.515 Popup[3242:303] +[NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:]: second object of each pair must be non-nil.  Or, did you forget to nil-terminate your parameter list?
2013-09-03 16:52:31.519 Popup[3242:303] (
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff9800a0a6 __exceptionPreprocess + 198
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00007fff9920b3f0 objc_exception_throw + 43
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff97fe8e31 +[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:] + 433
    3   Popup                               0x00000001000035a0 -[PanelController btnLapWasClicked:] + 192
    4   AppKit                              0x00007fff96082a59 -[NSApplication sendAction:to:from:] + 342
    5   AppKit                              0x00007fff960828b7 -[NSControl sendAction:to:] + 85
    6   AppKit                              0x00007fff960827eb -[NSCell _sendActionFrom:] + 138
    7   AppKit                              0x00007fff96080cd3 -[NSCell trackMouse:inRect:ofView:untilMouseUp:] + 1855
    8   AppKit                              0x00007fff96080521 -[NSButtonCell trackMouse:inRect:ofView:untilMouseUp:] + 504
    9   AppKit                              0x00007fff9607fc9c -[NSControl mouseDown:] + 820
    10  AppKit                              0x00007fff9607760e -[NSWindow sendEvent:] + 6853
    11  AppKit                              0x00007fff96073744 -[NSApplication sendEvent:] + 5761
    12  AppKit                              0x00007fff95f892fa -[NSApplication run] + 636
    13  AppKit                              0x00007fff95f2dcb6 NSApplicationMain + 869
    14  Popup                               0x0000000100001652 main + 34
    15  Popup                               0x0000000100001624 start + 52
)
```

Any ideas how to implement what I'm trying to do in another fashion that won't confuse the program?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use the modern obj-c notation. That enables you to create dictionaries and arrays in a more natural way.

```
NSDictionary *dic = @{@"Laps ": @(numLaps), @"someotherkey":@"anditswalue"};
```

In the code you show the keys and values are not in pairs. You must always insert pairs. (For detailed reference see the [NSDictionary documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSDictionary_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSDictionary/dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys%3a).)

```
NSString *key = @"laps";
NSString *value = [NSStringWithFormat:@"Lap %i", numLaps];
[arrayController addObject: [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
        value, key, nil]];
```

Also, you need to think over what you want to store in the dictionary. The keys and values are not apparent in your example.

Comment: I managed to figure it out. I took numLaps, converted it to a string, and made another string called numLapsString that held "Laps (numLaps)" (THAT IS NOT CODE). Then I just plugged that in for the first parameter, and it worked! Yay!

Comment: Hey I have a quick question though. I want to reset my Table View when I click the reset button. I've made the reset button, linked it and all that, I'm just not sure where to begin with removing the data from there. I'm learning as I go, but a lot of what I find on this is relating to iPhone programming which is slightly different :/

Comment: I suggest you ask this in a separate question. There aren't many resources for OSX and it's better to have more of them. But to answer your question in part, clear the data from your data source and call reloadData on the TableView. https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UITableView/reloadData

Comment: I suggest you create a question from this and answer it yourself. I'll upvote both if you post the link here.